# Using "0dp" height on TextView inside LinearLayout is not valid

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight = "2"
        android:text="some text"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight = "1"
        android:text="more text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The line `android:layout_height="0dp"` is not valid. The error says "Suspicious size, the view will be invisible". I want to make the tile textview 2 times bigger than the description textview using weight property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

May be you should use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight = "2"
    android:text="some text"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:text="more text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using **layout_weight** instead of **weight**.